# Proxy setting in gsutil tool

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I use gsutil tool for download archives from Google Storage.
I use next CMD command:

```
python c:\gsutil\gsutil cp gs://pubsite_prod_rev_XXXXXXXXXXXXX/YYYYY/*.zip C:\Tmp\gs
```

Everything works fine, but if I try to run that command from corporate proxy, I receive error:

```
Caught socket error, retrying: [Errno 10051] A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network
```

I tried several times to set the proxy settings in .boto file, but all to no avail. 
Someone faced with such a problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please see the section "I'm connecting through a proxy server, what do I need to do?" at https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/faq#troubleshooting

Basically, you need to configure the proxy settings in your .boto file, and you need to ensure that your proxy allows traffic to accounts.google.com as well as to *.storage.googleapis.com.

Comment: Thanks for answer! But I still can't make it work :(

Comment: Are you able to login to your proxy? If so, what happens if you run this command from that machine: traceroute storage.googleapis.com

Comment: Yes, I'm able to login. Here [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68469457/Temp/tracert%20storage.googleapis.com.txt) results of tracert. Thanks!

Comment: Here .boto proxy settings: `proxy = proxy.domain.ru
proxy_port = 8080
proxy_user = Vorobyev_E
proxy_pass = MyPassword`

Comment: From your tracert I can see your proxy itself is able to reach *.storage.googleapis.com, so I believe the proxy is blocking gsutil traffic - either the OAuth2 requests (to accounts.google.com) or the GCS API requests (to storage.googleapis.com). Does your proxy config require whitelisting the networks you're allowed to connect to? Have you added all Google IP address ranges to this whitelist as described at the above troubleshooting link?

Comment: Sorry, I incorrectly described the problem. If I set the proxy settings in .boto file I receive next error: `Failure: (407, 'Proxy Authentication Required').` If I don't set proxy settings I receive error: `[Errno 10051] A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network`

Answer (score 1):

A change was just merged into github yesterday that fixes some of the proxy support. Please try it out, or specifically, overwrite this file with your current copy:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/blob/master/gslib/util.py

Comment: No, it didn't change anything :(

Comment: If you run "gstuil -d ls" does it also trigger the same error? Also, in that output, does a "proxy: " line show up?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I am having the same problem with the proxy settings being ignored under Linux (Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS) and gsutils 4.2 (downloaded today).

I've been watching tcpdump on the host to confirm that gsutils is attempting to directly route to Google IPs instead of to my proxy server.

It seems that on the first execution of a simple command like "gsutil -d ls" it will use my proxy settings specified .boto for the first POST and then switch back to attempting to route directly to Google instead of my proxy server.

Then if I CTRL-C and re-run the exact same command, the proxy setting is no longer used at all. This difference in behaviour baffles me. If I wait long enough, I think it will work for the initial request again so this suggests some form on caching taking place. I'm not 100% of this behaviour yet because I haven't been able to predict when it occurs.

I also noticed that it always first tries to connect to 169.254.169.254 on port 80 regardless of proxy settings. A grep shows that it's hardcoded into oauth2_client.py, test_utils.py, layer1.py, and utils.py (under different subdirectories of the gsutils root).

I've tried setting the http_proxy environment variable but it appears that there is code that unsets this.

Comment: Reading my debug output (gsutils -d ls) in more depth I noticed that it creates an oauth cache file in my /tmp/ folder. If I delete that file and re-run "gsutils -d ls" then it will use my proxy setting for the POST /o/oath2/token, receive a response (since it used the proxy) but then when it continues to issue a GET request, the proxy is no longer used (verified by watching tcpdump) so it will keep retrying and report "Caught socket error, retrying: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable" (slightly different than OP's error.